# how to make click button in bootstrap and all data are come API

Tags: reactjs

**react**
if u can see code below i try to make when i click on true button or false button then according to click dada change and all data come from API

```
_filterByLaunch = launch => {
    const post = this.state.allPosts.filter(item =>
    item.launch_success === launch
    );
    this.setState({ post });
    }
```

You can see here and here is API URL https://api.spaceXdata.com/v3/launches?limit=100&launch_success=true

[Demo](https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv)

Comment: when i click on true or false then data not show and all data come from api as you can see here https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv

Comment: any body help me out its very thankful

Comment: why not working??

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when calling _filterByLaunch, pass the boolean type of `true` and `false` and not a string `'true'` and `'false'`. The data type in the response is of type boolean.

`launch_success: true   //NOT launch_success: 'true'`

so use `_filterByLaunch(true)`, NOT `_filterByLaunch('true')`

```
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onClick={() => this._filterByLaunch(true)}>true</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success"  onClick={() => this._filterByLaunch(false)}>false</button>
```

Comment: same thing i m implment in landing button but data not show??you can check here https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv

Comment: api url  https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches?limit=100

Comment: item.launch_landing does not exist in your data.

Comment: and how to use mission name with flight number

Comment: https://codepen.io/namratasep6/pen/JjXoxBv here you can see name with no.

Comment: plz help me out

Comment: best to console.log() your api data, and inspect the data structure to extract what you need.